# Swift receives data from device by BLE

Tags: c++, swift, boolean, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a device that transmits by BLE a message composed in this way: [STX]A1[ETX]

This device use a software written in C++ and 3rd character is a boolean!

Now, I would receive this message by iOS using swift. Other incoming message  it received correctly, but this one not.

This is a method in C++ that trasmits:

```
isModeOn = (byte)data[1] == 1 ? true : false;

//Send message by BLE (by Serial)
Serial3.write(STX);
Serial3.write(GF);
Serial3.write(isModeOn);
Serial3.write(ETX);
```

This is my method in swift that receives:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    print(#function)
    var receivedMessage: String

    if characteristic.uuid == BLE_RX_UUID {

        receivedMessage = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
        processMessage(receivedMessage: "\(receivedMessage as String)")
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE!
I found this approach:

```
//Lettura fecilitata dei NSData
struct DataReader {
    var data: Data
    var offset: Int = 0

    mutating func read() -> UInt8 {
        let result = data[offset]
        offset += MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
        return result
    }
    mutating func read2() -> UInt16 {
        let subdata = data.subdata(in: offset..<offset+MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size)
        let result: UInt16 = subdata.withUnsafeBytes {(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) in
            bytes.pointee.littleEndian
        }
        offset += MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
        return result
    }
}
```

with this I can received easely my data

```
var reader = MessageHelper.DataReader.init(data: receivedMessage, offset: 0)

    for _ in 1...reader.data.count {
        let value = reader.read()

        if value == STX {
            incomingMessage = ""
        } else if value == ETX {
            print(#function, incomingMessage)
            commandSelector(message: incomingMessage)
        } else {
            if value == 0x01 {
                incomingMessage += "1"
            } else if value == 0x00 {
                incomingMessage += "0"
            } else {
                incomingMessage += "\(Character(UnicodeScalar(value)))"
            }
        }
    }
```

OK! And If I need to send same message

```
sendMessage(message: String("\(COMMAND)\(Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(1))))"), withResponde: true)
```

I have to convert UInt8(1) in UnicodeScalar and then Character, and that's it!

Comment: How do you know the incoming message is received incorrectly?  Is there an error message you can show us?

Comment: What do you get with `print(characteristic.value! as NSData)` ?

Comment: I received [STX]A\0[ETX], then 4 character, but \0 it should be 1 or 0 (respectively true and false). I don't know how can I format this message... Could I format in byte array? How? I would like to avoid converting the message to a string....

Comment: I found an approach to decode received message